# Unable to find link with Capybara in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, poltergeist

I'm trying to test code that has asynchronous javascript and my test  fails from time to time.

```
scenario 'User can delete his comment', js: true do
  within('.answer') do
    click_link 'Comments (0)'
    find_link('Add Comment').click
    fill_in 'comment[content]', with: 'MyComment'
    click_on 'Post comment'
  end

  within('.comment') do
    click_link 'Delete'
  end

  expect(page).to have_text('Your comment has been deleted.')
end
```

The failure message is:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
  Unable to find link "Add Comment"
```

As I understand, `find_link` method has built-in wait functionality. Where is my mistake?

I use poltergeist as js driver and my config is:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10

options = { js_errors: false }
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end
```

Comment: click_link is identical to find_link(...).click so there is no need to use the second form.  If the test intermittently fails and the first click triggers a request then check your test log to see what's being submitted.  If the test always fails check the case of the link text on your page

Comment: @Tom, thanks a lot for the help!